# Can I change stream access from read type to readanswrite? System.NotSupportedException: 'Stream does not support writing

Tags: c#, .net

I get Stream readonly from graph rest api and I need to change something and update it. (without download) Can I change it to readwrite?

```
Stream WordStream = target.ItemWithPath("word.docx").Content
                                                    .Request().GetAsync() 
                                                    .GetAwaiter().GetResult();


WordprocessingDocument word = WordprocessingDocument.Open(WordStream, true);
```

error: System.NotSupportedException: 'Stream does not support writing.'

Comment: "*I need to change something and update it. (without download)*" -- how would that work? You need to download that response before you can read it. `WordStream` is a means to download the data stored on the server: being able to change it would imply that you could change what's on the server, which isn't the case. You need to download the response anyway: just download it to a `MemoryStream` (e.g. `var ms = new MemoryStream(); WordStream.CopyTo(ms)`, then `ms.Position = 0` and `WordprocessingDocument.Open(ms)`)

Comment: You're working with HTTP, not files. You can't write to an HTTP response stream, much less use it to modify anything on the server. As the name says, it's a *response* to an HTTP request. If you want to update a document you'll have to use the appropriate HTTP operation (POST, PUT, PATCH)

Comment: Why `GetAwaiter().GetResult();` ? Blocking an async operation is a bad idea and should only be used as a last resort. Make your method asynchronous and use `await`.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Async is bad for streams. When to Use Async The best general approach is to first think about what the application is actually doing. Async excels at I/O-bound operations, but there are sometimes better options for other kinds of processing. There are two somewhat common scenarios where async isn’t a perfect fit—CPU-bound code and data streams. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2015/july/async-programming-brownfield-async-development

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I know that. Problem was with stream being read only and not readwrite.

Comment: @canton7 Yea, I meant I didnt want "hard" save to file and I didnt care about memory save (I hope you understand) Thank you for the asnwer

Answer (score 0):

If what you are trying to do is update a WORD document using graph API
you need to first get the content of the file, with the stream you already have

And then you can update the file again as explained here

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/driveitem-update?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http

Comment: I know that. Problem was with stream being read only and not readwrite.

Comment: Did you share with us that you already new this ? and if you are getting a ReadStream it can not be "converted" to WriteStream that is not how streams work. you need a new one

Comment: Yea maybe it wasnt good explanation of my problem. That was my question. Now I know. ```MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(); WordStream.CopyTo(ms); ms.Position = 0;``` PS I meant I didnt want hard save(save to file, not memory)